# Why does calling std::string.c_str() on a function that returns a string not work?

Tags: c++, string, temporary, object-lifetime

I have the following code:

```
std::string getString() {
    std::string str("hello");
    return str;
}

int main() {
    const char* cStr = getString().c_str();
    std::cout << cStr << std::endl; // this prints garbage
}
```

What I thought would happen is that `getString()` would return a *copy* of `str` (`getString()` returns by value); thus, the copy of `str` would stay "alive" in `main()` until `main()` returns. This would make `cStr` point to a valid memory location: the underlying `char[]` or `char*` (or whatever) of the copy of `str` returned by `getString()` which, remains in `main()`.

However, this is obviously not the case, as the program outputs garbage. So, the question is, when is `str` destroyed, and why?

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: @PriyanshGoel Undefined behavior is like that sometimes.

Comment: I am not able get why the behaviour in undefined.

Comment: If you called this in a loop, would you expect all of them to stay alive until `main()` returns?

Comment: I love this site. With careful phrasing, even some pretty obscure issues are easy to find.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> `getString()` would return a copy of `str` (`getString()` returns by value);

It's right.

> thus, the copy of `str` would stay "alive" in `main()` until `main()` returns.

No, the returned copy is a temporary `std::string`, which will be destroyed at the end of the statement in which it was created, i.e. before `std::cout << cStr << std::endl;`. Then `cStr` becomes dangled, dereference on it leads to *UB*, anything is possible.

You can copy the returned temporary to a named variable, or bind it to a `const` lvalue-reference or rvalue-reference (the lifetime of the temporary will be extended until the reference goes out of scope). Such as:

```
std::string s1 = getString();    // s1 will be copy initialized from the temporary
const char* cStr1 = s1.c_str();
std::cout << cStr1 << std::endl; // safe

const std::string& s2 = getString(); // lifetime of temporary will be extended when bound to a const lvalue-reference
const char* cStr2 = s2.c_str();
std::cout << cStr2 << std::endl; // safe

std::string&& s3 = getString();  // similar with above
const char* cStr3 = s3.c_str();
std::cout << cStr3 << std::endl; // safe
```

Or use the pointer before the temporary gets destroyed. e.g.

```
std::cout << getString().c_str() << std::endl;  // temporary gets destroyed after the full expression
```

Here is an explanation from *[The.C++.Programming.Language.Special.Edition] 10.4.10 Temporary Objects [class.temp]]*:

> Unless bound to a reference or used to initialize a named object, a
> temporary object is destroyed at the end of the full expression in
> which it was created. A full expression is an expression that is
> not a subexpression of some other expression.
>
> The standard string class has a member function c_str() that
> returns a C-style, zero-terminated array of characters (§3.5.1, §20.4.1). Also, the operator + is defined to mean string concatenation.
> These are very useful facilities for strings . However, in combination they can cause obscure problems.
> For example:
>
> ```
> void f(string& s1, string& s2, string& s3)
> {
>
>     const char* cs = (s1 + s2).c_str();
>     cout << cs ;
>     if (strlen(cs=(s2+s3).c_str())<8 && cs[0]==´a´) {
>         // cs used here
>     }
>
> }
> ```
>
> Probably, your first reaction is "but don’t do that," and I agree.
> However, such code does get written, so it is worth knowing how it is
> interpreted.
>
> A temporary object of class string is created to hold s1 + s2 .
> Next, a pointer to a C-style string is extracted from that object. Then
> – at the end of the expression – the temporary object is deleted. Now,
> where was the C-style string allocated? Probably as part of the
> temporary object holding s1 + s2 , and that storage is not guaranteed
> to exist after that temporary is destroyed. Consequently, cs points
> to deallocated storage. The output operation cout << cs might work
> as expected, but that would be sheer luck. A compiler can detect and
> warn against many variants of this problem.

Comment: But saving the temporary std::string in a variable like: std::string str = getString(); won't destroy the copy? why not? is it because the = uses the copy constructor?

Comment: I am sorry but I am failing to understand this. I agree that str will be destroyed but then I have already stored the value of string.c_str in another variable. It should print hello.

Comment: @FakeJake Yes, the named variable `str` will be copy initialized from the temporary variable, (even though the copy will be omitted usually by RVO), then `str` will be valid until `main()` ends, so it'll be safe to use `str.c_str()` in `main()`.

Comment: @PriyanshGoel `std::string::c_str()` will return a pointer, yes we could save the pointer to another variable, but the memory the pointer pointing to, it's allocated by `std::string`, will be destroyed either when the `std::string` destroyed. Then the pointer saved in another variable will be a dangled pointer.

Comment: @songyuanyao, Can you please make your answer more detailed. I mean add the things you have mentioned in the comments to the answer itself.

Comment: @songyuanyao : Yes that seems correct to me. But with that logic it should always display garbage, right?  But here it works for me http://ideone.com/CgxK6d

Comment: @AkshayArora Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @PriyanshGoel I've added some more explanation in my answer. Even it seems to work well, dereferencing on deallocated memory *is* UB, anything is possible.

Comment: @songyuanyao : Thanks for the awesome explanation . It helped me a lot to get the concept right!

Comment: What about adding another one to your 3 suggestion of a correct code? Namely, a one-liner: `std::cout << getString().c_str() << std::endl;` (correct since it won't be destroyed "the end of the full expression").

Answer (score 6):

Problem here is that you are returning a temporary variable and over
that temporary variable you are doing c_str function.

> "c_str() function Returns a pointer to an array that contains a null-terminated 
>   sequence of characters (i.e., a C-string) representing the current
>   value of the string object(
>   [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/][1]).

In this case your pointer is pointing to memory location which is now not present.

```
std::string getString() {
        std::string str("hello");
        return str; // Will create Temporary object as it's return by value}

    int main() {
         const char* cStr = getString().c_str(); // Temporary object is destroyed
        std::cout << cStr << std::endl; // this prints garbage }
```

Solution is to copy your temporary object to memory location properly(by creating local copy) and then use c_str over that object.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by others you are using a pointer to temporary after it has already been deleted - this is a classic example of **heap after free use**.

What I can add to others' answers is that you can easily detect such usage with [gcc's](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) or [clang's](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) address sanitizers.

Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string get()
{
  return "hello";
}

int main()
{
  const char* c = get().c_str();
  std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

sanitizer output:

```
=================================================================
==2951==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x60300000eff8 at pc 0x7f78e27869bb bp 0x7fffc483e670 sp 0x7fffc483de20
READ of size 6 at 0x60300000eff8 thread T0
    #0 0x7f78e27869ba in strlen (/usr/lib64/libasan.so.2+0x6d9ba)
    #1 0x39b4892ba0 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) (/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6+0x39b4892ba0)
    #2 0x400dd8 in main /tmp/tmep_string/main.cpp:12
    #3 0x39aa41ed5c in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x39aa41ed5c)
    #4 0x400c48  (/tmp/tmep_string/a.out+0x400c48)

0x60300000eff8 is located 24 bytes inside of 30-byte region [0x60300000efe0,0x60300000effe)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f78e27ae6ea in operator delete(void*) (/usr/lib64/libasan.so.2+0x956ea)
    #1 0x39b489d4c8 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6+0x39b489d4c8)
    #2 0x39aa41ed5c in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x39aa41ed5c)

previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f78e27ae1aa in operator new(unsigned long) (/usr/lib64/libasan.so.2+0x951aa)
    #1 0x39b489c3c8 in std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6+0x39b489c3c8)
    #2 0x400c1f  (/tmp/tmep_string/a.out+0x400c1f)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free ??:0 strlen
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c067fff9da0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff9db0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff9dc0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff9dd0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff9de0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
=>0x0c067fff9df0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fd fd fd[fd]
  0x0c067fff9e00: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff9e10: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff9e20: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff9e30: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff9e40: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Heap right redzone:      fb
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack partial redzone:   f4
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
==2951==ABORTING
```

Comment: I guess you mean "heap use after free" ; there is not necessarily any heap involved here (string may use SSO to avoid needing to allocate a buffer)