# C++ ExpandEnvironmentStringsForUser function somtimes returns wrong value

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm using **ExpandEnvironmentStringsForUser** function to expand a directory which includes environment variable.
However, the returned value is sometimes wrong.

My process is running with system privilege.

E.g:

- Input string: "C:\Users\%username%\Documents\"
- Output string (maybe one of following strings)

C:\Users\cuong.huynh\Documents\ (expected output)

C:\Users\cuong.huynh\AppData\Roaming (wrong)

C:\Program Files\Common Files (wrong)

My brief code is as follows:

```
DWORD dwSessionID = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionID, &hUserToken);
DuplicateToken(hUserToken, SecurityImpersonation, &hDuplicated)
hToken = hDuplicated;

LPCWSTR DesPath = (StringUtil::StrToWstr(setting)).c_str(); //(input)
wchar_t ExpandedDesPath[MAX_PATH]; //(output)

ExpandEnvironmentStringsForUser(hToken, DesPath, ExpandedDesPath, MAX_PATH - 1)
```

Does anyone know the reason why the output is not stable?

Comment: I've never once had it return the wrong value. Please provide an actual, full [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. (That [mcve] should be able to be copied, pasted, compiled and executed, and demonstrate the issue you're having. It should contain the exact input that you're providing that produces different results when used  multiple times.)

Comment: Sounds like `setting` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: for what you call `DuplicateToken` ?!

Comment: Thank everyone,
The issue was fixed as below Remy's solution.

Comment: You should be using the shell functions to get these paths.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does calling std::string.c\_str() on a function that returns a string not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35980664/why-does-calling-stdstring-c-str-on-a-function-that-returns-a-string-not-wor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LPCWSTR DesPath = (StringUtil::StrToWstr(setting)).c_str();`
```

This creates a **temporary** `wstring` that goes out of scope immediately after `DesPath` is assigned, leaving `DestPath` dangling and pointing at invalid memory. You need to store the result of `StrToWstr()` to a local `wstring` variable first before then calling `c_str()` on it, so the string memory stays in scope:

```
wstring wstr = StringUtil::StrToWstr(setting);
LPCWSTR DesPath = wstr.c_str();
```

Otherwise, call `StrToWstr().c_str()` directly in the input parameter of `ExpandEnvironmentStringsForUser()`:

```
ExpandEnvironmentStringsForUser(hToken, StringUtil::StrToWstr(setting).c_str(), ExpandedDesPath, MAX_PATH - 1);
```