# ID:danglingTemporaryLifetime Using pointer to temporary.: C: conditionally change value of const char function parameter inside the function

Tags: c++, string, char, c-strings

Consider I have a C function:

```
MyFunction(const char *value, bool trigger)
```

Inside, depending on the value of the `trigger` variable, I'd like to either use a `value` provided to the function or simply overwrite it with some other `const char` string returned by a different function, e.g.:

```
MyFunction(const char *value, bool trigger) {
if (trigger) {
     value = anotherFunctionReturningConstChar().c_str();
}
// do processing here

}
```

What is the correct way to achieve this, considering the pointers and their type. As far as I understand, I cannot simply change the value of the function parameter and I need to use some third variable which should be set to either a `value` or to the result of `anotherFunction`.

I'm getting the following error right now in the static analyzer:
[ID:danglingTemporaryLifetime] Using pointer to temporary.

What does it mean and how can I overcome it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does calling std::string.c\_str() on a function that returns a string not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35980664/why-does-calling-stdstring-c-str-on-a-function-that-returns-a-string-not-wor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can assign to a function parameter exactly as you did. This doesn't affect the caller in any way.

Comment: I tried that, but getting the following error:
` [ID:danglingTemporaryLifetime] Using pointer to temporary.`

Comment: @RichardTopchii We'll need a [mcve].

Comment: Updated my question, the code actually works well, but I'm getting the static analyzer error now. Curious, what does it mean and how can I overcome it.

Comment: Maybe this is also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35980664/why-does-calling-stdstring-c-str-on-a-function-that-returns-a-string-not-wor

Comment: @RichardTopchii Assuming `anotherFunctionReturningConstChar` returns by value, this is UB, since the string dies immediately, and the pointer becomes dangling. You need to save the result to a local `std::string` variable, call `.c_str()` on that variable, and ensure that it lives as long as you want to use the pointer.

Answer (score -1):

use `MyFunction(void  *value, bool trigger)` where you hold a pointer to a function or to a const char*  and then cast the value to the desired object but I think it is useless.