# My helper function is returning an empty string

Tags: c++, string, pointers, reverse-engineering

I'm writing some code for a game, and I'm attempting to write a helper function to return a string inside an object:

```cpp
const char* getGhostName(GhostAI* ghostAI)
{
    if (ghostAI) {
        GhostInfo* ghostInfo = getGhostInfo(ghostAI);
        const auto ghostName = ghostInfo->fields.u0A6Du0A67u0A74u0A71u0A71u0A66u0A65u0A68u0A74u0A6Au0A6F.u0A65u0A66u0A6Eu0A67u0A69u0A74u0A69u0A65u0A74u0A6Fu0A67;
        const char* name = il2cppi_to_string(ghostName).c_str();
        return name;
    }
    return "UNKNOWN";
}
```

And here is the `il2cppi_to_string` functions:

```cpp
std::string il2cppi_to_string(Il2CppString* str) {
    std::u16string u16(reinterpret_cast<const char16_t*>(str->chars));
    return std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t>{}.to_bytes(u16);
}

std::string il2cppi_to_string(app::String* str) {
    return il2cppi_to_string(reinterpret_cast<Il2CppString*>(str));
}
```

When I call `getGhostName`, I end up with an empty string. Now I did get a warning from ReSharper which says:

> Object backing the pointer will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression.

This is appearing on the following line inside `getGhostName` when calling `il2cppi_to_string`:

```cpp
const char* name = il2cppi_to_string(ghostName).c_str();
```

I'm not entirely sure what this means or how I can modify the code to fix it. I absolutely hate working with strings in C++.

Comment: Why not just keep using actual `std::string`s instead of trying to juggle `char` pointers?

Comment: You are calling `c_str` on a _temporary_ `std::string` object that will be destroyed before your `return` statement.

Comment: "I absolutely hate working with strings in C++." -- I'd say you just need to read a tutorial on C++ strings. You hate it because you're trying to fight a system that you don't understand.

Comment: "I absolutely hate working with strings in C++." -- Yet you decided to use `const char *` instead of staying with the much-easier-to-use `std::string`.   You sabotaged yourself by using `const char *`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does calling std::string.c\_str() on a function that returns a string not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35980664/why-does-calling-stdstring-c-str-on-a-function-that-returns-a-string-not-wor)

Comment: The unofficial rule of thumb is to use `std::string` throughout your code, and only resort to `c_str()` when you are calling a legacy or API function that only allows `const char *` as parameters.  Don't (as I mentioned in the previous comment) sabotage yourself by introducing `const char *` on purpose.

Comment: *"I absolutely hate working with strings in C++."* -- the term "string" can refer to two different beasts in C++ -- `std::string` and null-terminated C-style strings (using the types `char*` and `const char*`). My personal ranking for ease-of-use might be: 1) `std::string`; 2) C-style; 3) start working with C-style, then switch to working with `std::string`; 4) start working with `std::string`, then switch to working with C-style. (Some days I might swap #2 and #3.) You have chosen to use #4. Generalizing your experience with the hardest case to all cases is not exactly a fair assessment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`il2cppi_to_string()` returns a *temporary* `std::string`, which will be destroyed at the end of the expression that calls `il2cppi_to_string()`. You are obtaining a `const char*` pointer to the data of that *temporary* `std::string`, which is what ReSharper is warning you about. Since the *temporary* `std::string` is destroyed before the `return`, that means `getGhostName()` is returning a *dangling pointer to invalid memory*.

To fix this, change `getGhostName()` to return a `std::string` instead of a `const char*`:

```
std::string getGhostName(GhostAI* ghostAI)
{
    if (ghostAI) {
        GhostInfo* ghostInfo = getGhostInfo(ghostAI);
        const auto ghostName = ghostInfo->fields.u0A6Du0A67u0A74u0A71u0A71u0A66u0A65u0A68u0A74u0A6Au0A6F.u0A65u0A66u0A6Eu0A67u0A69u0A74u0A69u0A65u0A74u0A6Fu0A67;
        return il2cppi_to_string(ghostName);
    }
    return "UNKNOWN";
}
```